# Copy realm+objectmapper object

Tags: swift, object, copy, realm, objectmapper

I was trying to find solution to copy object of realm+objectmapper with no success and found out that it is still an [open issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3381).

I have to change properties of my object and don't want to do it in a write transaction on a "wrong place" and passing update values is not easy...

Does anybody of you did workaround to copy.

To be more specific please find below as an example a part of my class...

```
class User : Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    let height = RealmOptional<Int>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map){
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        height.value <- map["height"]
        firstName <- map["firstName"]
        lastName <- map["lastName"]
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you have left out the relevant part of your class definition, but the problem of not having the ability of making a deep copy comes into the picture when you have relations to other managed Realm objects. In this example the User class does not have any relations to other Realm objects, so I don't see why you would need to make a deep copy.

Comment: Well, I have user settings update part which in the end rest call to backend server but 1-st problem is that the update request is a part of user object kind a dictionary only of firstName and height, 2-nd problem is that the update values holds by controller which has nothing to do with realm as doesn't have clue from where object comes from (realm, coredata, pure json...). So I need to cut/merge object to get correct request as dictionary to send update request. P.S. please note that the example I provided is a 1% of what I have to change.

Comment: I'm still not sure how deep copying ties into this. Can you update your question to elaborate on what you're attempting to do, what you've tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @bdash, thanks for comment, sorry for late reply..
Let' keep it simple and remove "deep" word from question, I want to copy the example I provided in the question.